# Snowflake - Error parsing JSON: invalid character outside of a string: '/'

Tags: python, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

Snowflake is giving me a headache loading JSON data into a table.

Loading the JSON file through an external stage via an airflow dag task returns this error:

ERROR - Failed to execute job 856 for task copy_raw_data (100069 (22P02): 01b2ef42-3201-1fd5-0000-00052d827631: Error parsing JSON: invalid character outside of a string: '/'
File 'transactions/transactions.json', line 1, character 1
Row 0, column $1

Here is the sample JSON code that's returning the error:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3f8e52c7f8d84f63a28c7d3174a825e7",
        "date": "01102023",
        "items": [
            {
                "product_id": "10052645",
                "price": 995.0
            },
            {
                "product_id": "10206747",
                "price": 3599.0
            }
        ],
        "customer": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Virginie Paradis",
            "email": "VirginieParadis@email.com",
            "address": "1095 allé Lemire, L'-L'-Nadeau, QC Y1Y 9A3",
            "phone": "945-434-8939x061",
            "card_number": "********5089"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the airflow task:

```
    copy_raw_data = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='copy_raw_data',
    snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_staging_conn',
    sql="""
        COPY INTO "STORE"."STAGING"."RAW_DATA"
        FROM @s3_data_pipeline_repo
        FILES=('transactions.json')
        FILE_FORMAT=(
            TYPE=JSON,
            STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY=TRUE,
            REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS=TRUE,
            DATE_FORMAT=AUTO,
            TIME_FORMAT=AUTO,
            TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=AUTO
        )
        MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_INSENSITIVE
        ON_ERROR=ABORT_STATEMENT
        """,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Here is the table command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE staging.raw_data (
  id STRING,
  date STRING,
  customer OBJECT,
  items VARIANT
);
```

I checked for BOM at the beginning of the file since the error specified "line 1, character 1" but none are found with hexdump command or with any JSON validators.

When loading the data manually in the Snowflake interface and manually choosing the file on the system file directory the data loads no problem!?!?

Similar issues stated that changing column data type to VARCHAR would fix but it didn't and many other dag runs use this format and work perfectly well.

Any ideas is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Your table definition that you are loading into isn't correct for the COPY command that you are issuing unless there is more in the file that you are not sharing.  You should be loading the entire JSON into a single variant column in your raw_data.  You can then create a view over it to separate the fields out into separate columns, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment to your question.  Everything you have for the JSON structure and the `COPY INTO` command seem good to me.  Assuming that this is the entire data you are trying to load, then I'd recommend doing this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE staging.raw_data (
  payload VARIANT
);
```

And then create a view over that table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW staging.vw_raw_data_flat as
SELECT
  payload:id::string as id,
  payload:date::string as date, ## not a good column name
  payload:customer::variant as customer
  payload:items::variant
FROM staging.raw_data;
```

In theory, you could also create separate columns for the the customer attributes quite easily, as well, if needed.